# How can set different session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, timeout

How we can set different session timeout in each part of a website in asp.net c#.

I know that we can manage session timeout by web config but when we change session timeout in web config the specified value set for all of my website but I want to manage session timeout in my program for example in administrator want to set session timeout 2 hours and in login user area set session timeout to 10 minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the SessionTimeout of the current HttpContext. When an administrator logs in, just change his timeout like this:

`HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60;`

http://forums.asp.net/t/1563991.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko - Applied your suggestions. Thx!