# How to increase or decrease session timeout from other then web config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, web-config

How to increase or decrease session timeout from other then web config file?

As in my schenario, I have to fix the session timeout for all user, but for some specific user I need to decrease it manually from code.

I tried to set the session timeout using below code but it did not work.

FormsAuthenticationConfiguration obj = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration();
obj.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

Answer (score 0):

On the `Session_OnStart` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx), you can call `HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 1;` as specified here:[How can set different session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381956/how-can-set-different-session-timeout)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will implement the same and let you know.